# Pytest mock / patch of an api call

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I am trying to understand patching, but I seem to be failing to do so.

Currently I am trying to patch an api call inside of the tested function:

```py
# function being tested
def tested_function():
   response = call_to_api()
   status = response["status"]
   if status == "something":
   # some more logic to test
```

In the `test_file.py` I attempt to do the following:

```py
@patch("import_from_same_file.call_to_api")
def test_tested_function(my_mock):
    my_mock.return_value = {"status":"COMPLETE"}
```

All I've been able to achieve so far is `Got error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` error with no clue where is it actually coming from. Please help, already spent so many hours on this.

I have also tried to supply an object as a return value of the mock.

```py
class Response():
   status = "COMPLETE"
```

With no luck though. Apparently I am missing something about how the patching works.

Comment: Is `"import_from_same_file.call_to_api"` definitely correct? Put a `breakpoint` in `tested_function` to see what response you're getting. You need to mock `call_to_api`, from where it's being called, not where it's defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what is going wrong, without seeing the call stack, but the following general pattern works.

`foo.py`

```py
def foo():
    pass


def bar():
    result = foo()
    return result["status"]
```

The with `test_foo.py` as

```py
import mock

from foo import bar


@mock.patch("foo.foo", return_value={"status": "PASSED"})
def test_add(mock_foo):
    assert bar() == "PASSED"
```

This general pattern works with `pytest test_foo.py` in the same directory.